# Adding library to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have been trying to add a library to android studio and have encountered a few problems. I have looked everywhere and think I am doing this correctly, however, then, when I open a java file that is used by the API, it tells me that the sources aren't found.

The class WSClient is used by the vtwsclib.jar file and I have no clue on how to attach sources to this. The API used can be downloaded from this site http://forge.vtiger.com/frs/?group_id=181&release_id=573. I am using java to call the methods from the WSClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the jar file in your libs folder and add a dependency in your gradle file:

```
dependencies {
   compile files('libs/your_lib.jar')
}
```

Than sync your project and you'll be able to access the classes inside the jar file.

Comment: I have done all of that and still have the same problem. It states that the sources aren't found and gives me the option to attach them. However, I do not know what to attach.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting the .jar file in the "libs" folder of your project should work